# Ionic 4/5 - google maps in modal window with a service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, service, modal-dialog

I am showing maps in Ionic 5 with the javascript sdk.
I load these maps with a service created for that.

Everything is fine when I do it in pages but if I show one of those pages as modal, the map does not load and the marker places it on the page from which the modal window was opened instead of in the modal window itself.

Let's see if I can put the code below so that it is not too "heavy"

home.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      HOME
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <ion-button href = "page2" expand = "block">page 2</ion-button>
    <ion-button (click)="presentModal()" expand = "block" >page 3 modal</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

page2.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>page2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <ion-button href = "home" expand = "block" >home</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

page3.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>page3</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <ion-button href = "home" expand = "block" >home</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit }            from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController }              from '@ionic/angular';
import { LocationService }          from 'src/app/services/Location.service'
import { Page3Page }                    from 'src/app/pages/page3/page3.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public LocationService: LocationService,
                public ModalController: ModalController) {}

    ngOnInit () {
        this.LocationService.loadMap("home");
        }

    async presentModal() {
        const modal = await this.ModalController.create({
            component: Page3Page
            });
        return await modal.present();
        }
}
```

page2.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService }      from 'src/app/services/Location.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-page2',
    templateUrl: './page2.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page2.page.scss'],
    })
export class Page2Page implements OnInit {
    constructor(private LocationService: LocationService) {}

    ngOnInit () {
        //this.loadMap();
        this.LocationService.loadMap("page2");
        }
}
```

page3.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService }      from 'src/app/services/Location.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page3',
  templateUrl: './page3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page3.page.scss'],
})
export class Page3Page implements OnInit {
    constructor(private LocationService: LocationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.LocationService.loadMap("page3");
        }
}
```

location.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var google;

interface Marker {
    position: {
      lat: number,
      lng: number,
    };
    title: string;
  }

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {

    map = null;

    constructor() { }

    loadMap(prmtrMapId) {
        // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
        const mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
        var myLatLng, myTitle;
        var marker;
        // create LatLng object
        switch (prmtrMapId) {
            case "home": // No hay sentencia "break" en el 'case 0:', por lo tanto este caso también será ejecutado
                myLatLng = {lat: 54.1675272, lng: -7.5138625}; //england
                myTitle = "home -> England";
                break; // Al encontrar un "break", no será ejecutado el 'case 2:'
            case "page2":
                myLatLng = {lat: 51.713614, lng: 10.956151}; //deutschland 
                myTitle = "page2 -> Deutschland ";
                break;
            case "page3":
                myLatLng = {lat: 47.820012, lng: 3.490945}; //france
                myTitle = "page3 modal -> France";
                break;
            default:
                myLatLng = {lat: 4.658383846282959, lng: -74.09394073486328};
          }
       
        marker = {
            position: myLatLng,
            title: myTitle
            };

        // create map
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
            center: marker.position,
            zoom: 4
            });

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
            this.addMarker(marker);
        });
    }

    addMarker(marker: Marker) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker.position,
        map: this.map,
        title: marker.title
    });
    }
}
```

Any help is apreciated !

thanks a lot

Ernesto

Comment: I think if you open the modal dialog you create a second div with the id map. In you service you try to get the map id element which is probably the first one. try renaming the modal map element id and pass it along to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the elementRef and pass it along like this:

Change the service to this:

```
loadMap(prmtrMapId, elRef: ElementRef) {
   const mapEle: HTMLElement = elRef.nativeElement;
}
```

In Page3 change the html to

```
<ion-content>
    <div #map></div>
    <ion-button href = "home" expand = "block" >home</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

and in the ts add the ViewChild and call the service like this

```
@ViewChild('map') mapEl: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(){
   this.LocationService.loadMap("page3", this.mapEl);
}
```

Because "View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called." You need to use ngAfterViewInit or static: true.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

Comment: Yes,
the problem I present here is fixed referencing each div with diferent id

Thanks

but I need to test it in production app and I will tell you if it works, because I think I tried that solution and it didn't works.

I will tell you

Comment: @Ernesto Nice thanks. You could also try to use the ElementRef as argument so you dont have to use the document object at all. Like <div #modalMap></div> and then use the \@ViewChild decorator to obtain and pass that element. If you want i can adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: That would be perfect, I always mess with viewchild a bit and so I can work with him and get used to it, thank you very much @thecOdemOnkey

Comment: @Ernesto changed the answer to use ViewChild. Its dry coded but i think it should work.

Comment: @Ernesto np glad i could help. If you accept the answer i get bonus points and less ads ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check (by adding console.log) if this is fired when opening the modal :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.LocationService.loadMap("page3");

    }
```

Comment: Hello,

yes, that instruction is executed.
what happens is that the changes are produced in the map of the page that the modal has called, not in the modal itself.

The marker located in France should appear in the modal window and appears in the window that opened the modal.
And in the modal neither the map is loaded.
Greetings,

Ernesto

Comment: the problem is in the line that mentioned the previous user but I thought it was controlled, I test it with more deep and I will tell you